# `ApiRequestError: File not found`: ¿Cómo puedo subir un archivo csv a una carpeta específica de Google Drive con python en colaboratory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, google-drive, google-colab

Quiero subir un archivo csv a una carpeta `SugiPerso` en Google Drive, pero me sale un error `ApiRequestError: File not found`.

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from google.auth import default
creds, _ = default()

# récupérer l'ID du dossier cible
folder_id = 'SugiPerso'

gc = gspread.authorize(creds)
sh = gc.create('pdf_informations_test_upload')

# exporter la feuille de calcul dans Google Drive
file = drive.CreateFile({
    'title': 'pdf_informations_test_upload',
    'parents': [{'id': folder_id}],
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'
})

file.Upload()

# Choisir la feuille de calcul sur laquelle vous voulez charger les données
worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)

df_merged = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))


# Gérer les Nan
df_merged = df_merged.astype(str)

# Charger la dataframe dans la feuille de calcul
worksheet.update([df_merged.columns.values.tolist()] + df_merged.values.tolist())
```

En efecto, me devuelve el codigo:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py in _FilesInsert(self, param)
    367         param['media_body'] = self._BuildMediaBody()
--> 368       metadata = self.auth.service.files().insert(**param).execute(
    369         http=self.http)

5 frames
HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json returned "File not found: SugiPerso". Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: SugiPerso', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'file', 'locationType': 'other'}]">

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ApiRequestError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py in _FilesInsert(self, param)
    369         http=self.http)
    370     except errors.HttpError as error:
--> 371       raise ApiRequestError(error)
    372     else:
    373       self.uploaded = True

ApiRequestError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?alt=json returned "File not found: SugiPerso". Details: "[{'message': 'File not found: SugiPerso', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'location': 'file', 'locationType': 'other'}]">
```

Answer (score 0):

El error `"File not found: SugiPerso"` indica que la carpeta con el `ID 'SugiPerso'` no fue encontrada en Google Drive. Si la carpeta no existe, puedes crearla utilizando el siguiente código:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

# authenticate user and build Drive API client
creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_info(info)
service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# create folder with specified name and return ID
def create_folder(folder_name):
    file_metadata = {'name': folder_name, 'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'}
    folder = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, fields='id').execute()
    print(f'Folder has been created with Name "{folder_name}" and URL: "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/{folder.get("id")}".')
    return folder.get('id')

# create folder with name 'SugiPerso'
folder_id = create_folder('SugiPerso')
```

Una vez que tengas el ID de la carpeta, modifica la variable `folder_id` en el código que compartiste con el nuevo ID y debería funcionar correctamente.